# Sort TableChart with "Release Number" column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

Given a dataTable that includes a column of "Release Numbers", how can the resulting TableChart be sorted correctly on that column?

These are examples of the alphanumeric strings that represent "Release Numbers":

```
"1.0", "12.0.1", "2.10", "2.0.0.142", "2.0.0.1_2", "10.2"
```

The desired sort order for this sample would be:

```
"1.0", "2.0.0.2", "2.0.0.142", "2.10", "10.2", "12.0.1"
```

Because of the format of these values, they must be considered "Strings", and therefore are sorted alphabetically. This results in a list that's not in a logical "release" order:

```
"1.0", "10.2", "12.0.1", "2.0.0.142", "2.0.0.2", "2.10"
```

There are numerous solutions for comparing the values, so that's not the focus of this question. Rather, how can I custom-sort these "Strings", within the confines of Google Apps-Script?

Related posts:

- [How to compare software version number using js? (only number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number)
- [How to sort varchar column (SQL) that contains number, chars, characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541243/how-to-sort-varchar-column-sql-that-contains-number-chars-characters)
- [How Can I Sort A 'Version Number' Column Generically Using a SQL Server Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query)

Here's a code snippet lifted almost directly from [Gustavo Moura](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2011/09/visualize-your-data-charts-in-google.html).

You can try my version [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxk5xiLQ0Dvx9ZUE_yoOG_zL6QTK1v8Zlg3hMgn3B_rXS_NMMhF/exec).

```
function doGet() {    
  // Populate the DataTable.  We'll have the data labels in   
  // the first column, "Quarter", and then add two data columns,  
  // for "Income" and "Expenses"  
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Release")      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Income")      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses")      
        .addRow(["1.0", 60, 55])      
        .addRow(["10.2", 50, 60])      
        .addRow(["2.10", 100, 50])
        .addRow(["12.0.1", 70, 60])      
        .addRow(["2.0.0.142", 30, 50])
        .addRow(["2.0.0.1_2", 114, 75])
        .build();

  // Build the chart. 
  var chart = Charts.newTableChart()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)  
//    .setTitle("Income and Expenses per Release")
      .build();

  // Add our chart to the UI and return it so that we can publish  
  // this UI as a service and access it via a URL.  
  var ui = UiApp.createApplication();  
  ui.add(chart);  
  return ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide sorting functions to a Charts data table. However, before adding the data to the table, you could do your own sort on the data. Push each row to an array, and call .sort() with your own sorting function that compares version numbers in the first index of each row. The first link you posted looks like it has a good answer.

If you want to keep the data sorted in the table chart, disable sort on the TableChart so users can't change the ordering.

```
.setOption("sort", "disable")
```

I haven't tried this, but I don't think Google will automatically sort the data, breaking your own sort.

Comment: Thanks Frederic, but disabling sorting isn't an option here - The 'click to sort' feature is wanted.

Comment: This may not look as good, but you could make each portion of the release # a column: `.addRow(["12",".0",".1", 70, 60]`. I can't think of anything aside from that.

Comment: Thanks for the thought... I've taken it a bit further and created a function to normalize the release numbers in a single column. For example, '12.0.1' becomes '012.000.000.0000'. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it does satisfy the requirement of being able to sort by that column. Unfortunately, the numbers don't appear as they do in the input, so users are finding it confusing.

Comment: This might lead to more confusion, but if you sort the releases before adding them to the data table, you can add another "index" column 1..n and tell users to sort by that. I had to do something similar for a chart I had with monthly data where I had to create a filter using dates converted to numbers.

Comment: Just saw `showRowNumber` and `firstRowNumber` properties on the GViz Table documentation. These add a row number column. You can use chart properties in Google Apps Script using `.setOption(name, value)`

Comment: Good ideas, but not quite there. Adding `.setOption('showRowNumber', 'true')` to the tableChart does add row numbering, but the row numbers float - they are always ordered 1..n regardless of what column is used to sort the table. I guess they are an aid to counting rows, not a usable index.

Comment: I think that what I need is either support for a custom comparator for the column, or the ability to sort on a hidden column (i.e. click on "Release Number" would cause a sort on the hidden "Normalized Release Number" column). Neither of these features is supported by the bog-standard TableChart, so I'm looking at other options. Let's see what I find.